# Select fields from a form by ID or Xpath and fill its value

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I'm writing a program/tests in C# using Selenium and Chrome web driver. Everything works well, however I would like to simplify the code and make it object-oriented. I thought about extracting some parts of the code to different classes, and perhaps refactor the area of `driver.FindElement...` by using it only one time with different arguments.

Any suggestions?

```
private static void FillingForms(IWebDriver driver)
{

    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='payoutMethods']/label[1]")).Click();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("SignUpButton")).Click();
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("accountType_Company")).Click();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtCompanyName")).SendKeys("Albertos Example");

    var mySelectElm = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ddlBusinessOrganization"));
    var mySelect = new SelectElement(mySelectElm);
    mySelect.SelectByText("Trust Company");

    driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtCompanyURL")).SendKeys("www.examplewebsite.com");
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtContactPersonFirstName")).SendKeys("11 Name");
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtContactPersonLastName")).SendKeys("11 Last Name");

    var email = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n").Substring(0, 5);
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtEmail")).SendKeys(email + "@gmail.com");
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtRetypeEmail")).SendKeys(email + "@gmail.com");
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("datepicker")).Click();

    var mySelectElm1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div/div/select[2]"));
    var mySelect1 = new SelectElement(mySelectElm1);
    mySelect1.SelectByText("1988");

    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/a")).Click();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("PersonalDetailsButton")).Click();

}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your title to tell us **what your code does**, not what you want us to do with it.

Comment: Hope now is OK...

Comment: Create page objects and use them.

Answer (score 3):

- You use a lot of absolute xpaths. It's a bad practice, since those are costly to maintain and looks bad. Try to modify them to relative xpath's or preferably css selectors.
- Instead of implicit wait, use explicit wait and wait until certain conditions are met. Or if you test ajax based application - try waiting for ajax requests to complete.
- Seems that your application might have quite some dropdowns. Create extention
  `someElement.SelectByText(string text)`or static method `Select.ByText(someText).FromElement(someElements)` and initialize SelectElement there. It mostly good to abstract yourself from any lib.
- Check out PageFactory pattern - maybe you will like it. It's another way of finding elements - more readable and convenient.
- I don't advocate to use page object pattern since I think it is an anti pattern in any object oriented language, but for starter - try it.
- Why is your method static?